Returning All Results From a List vs FirstOrDefault Throws an Error in C#
I have a function that is returning a list of results from the TrustPilot API. We use this in our current stack to display only one review at a time.
I would like to duplicate this and return all results so that I can make a carousel out of these results. However, when I remove the FirstOrDefault method I get an error on my return variable.
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<DTC.Feature.MyProject.Rating.Models.Review>' to 'DTC.Foundation.MyProject.ApplicationUserInterface.Rating.IReview'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
What is the proper way to return these items? I thought I should possibly add ToList() but it's already a list.
public IReview GetReviews()
{
    var client = new BusinessUnitReviewRatingClient();
    var fullResponse = client.GetBusinessUnitRating(TrustPilotTheme.ProductPage);
    var reviews = fullResponse?.Reviews?.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);

    return reviews;
}
    

This is my response where I get the list - these values are all here when I check the debugger:
public class TrustPilotResponse
{
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    
}

Just in case it's helpful:
The Controller:
 public ActionResult StaticCarousel()
    {
        var reviews = _ratingService.GetReviews();
        CardPullQuoteModel CardPullQuote_model = null;

        if (reviews != null)
        {
            CardPullQuote_model = new CardPullQuoteModel
            {
                ConsumerName = reviews.ConsumerName,
                DateFormatted = reviews.TimeAgo,
                Stars = reviews.Stars,
                Title = reviews.Title,
                Url = reviews.ReviewUrl,
                Image = _trustpilotService?.GetLogo(),
                HideRatingInfo = "1" == RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull?.Rendering?.Parameters[CustomRenderingParameters.CardPullQuote.HideRatingInfo]
            };
        }
        TrustPilotCardModel model = new TrustPilotCardModel
        {
            CardPullQuoteModel = CardPullQuote_model,
            Color = _colorService.GetColorFromRenderingParameter()?.Name,
            Theme = TrustPilotTheme.StaticCarousel,
        };

        return View("CardPullQuote", model);
    }
}


public IReview GetReviews() <- that return type is a scalar, not a collection. But you are trying to return a collection. That's what the error message is telling you.  You need to change the return type.

Feel like not only change in the return type for the GetReviews method, this would also impact how you are going to create CardPullQuote_model (either you need to create one or multiple) and how you provide the instances to the CardPullQuoteModel property in the TrustPilotCardModel class.

if this is in Visual Studio, then you can hover your mouse over the var keyword to see the actual type you are declaring. every variable in C# has a specific type, and var just determines it automatically upon declaration. but in C# the type of a variable can't be changed after it has been declared (static typing), unlike in JavaScript (dynamic typing), despite it looking like var is a universal type. the types object and dynamic do behave in a similar way var does in JavaScript, but it's better to avoid these in C# with the benefit of catching obvious type errors at compile time
